# Facebook native SDK conflicts with Parse4CN1 on Android

Tags: codenameone, parse4cn1

I'm currently having some trouble with an issue that was previously fixed through a build hint some time ago as you can see in the following thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/codenameone-discussions/parse4cn1%7Csort:date/codenameone-discussions/4xipU9Sy5rY/IbX1YMmGBQAJ

```
I'm still keeping the build hint android.excludeBolts=true as well as the facebook.appId build hint set to my app id, but it now fails with the following error:

2019-03-19 00:35:44.832 9571-9571/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.guarumo.ego, PID: 9571
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lbolts/AppLinks;
        at com.facebook.appevents.internal.SourceApplicationInfo$Factory.create(SourceApplicationInfo.java:131)
        at com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker.onActivityCreated(ActivityLifecycleTracker.java:155)
        at com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker$1.onActivityCreated(ActivityLifecycleTracker.java:101)
        at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:208)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1110)
        at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.onCreate(CodenameOneActivity.java:306)
        at com.guarumo.ego.EgoStub.onCreate(EgoStub.java:53)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bolts.AppLinks" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.guarumo.ego-nsZJW8Y8XXNjxF5pwA3RMQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.guarumo.ego-nsZJW8Y8XXNjxF5pwA3RMQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.facebook.appevents.internal.SourceApplicationInfo$Factory.create(SourceApplicationInfo.java:131) 
        at com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker.onActivityCreated(ActivityLifecycleTracker.java:155) 
        at com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker$1.onActivityCreated(ActivityLifecycleTracker.java:101) 
        at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:208) 
        at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1110) 
        at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.onCreate(CodenameOneActivity.java:306) 
        at com.guarumo.ego.EgoStub.onCreate(EgoStub.java:53) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

On the other hand, if I set the android.excludeBolts build hint to false I get the problem presented on the previously mentioned thread:

```
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbolts/AggregateException;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbolts/AndroidExecutors;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbolts/AndroidExecutors$1;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbolts/AndroidExecutors$UIThreadExecutor;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbolts/BoltsExecutors;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbolts/BoltsExecutors$1;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbolts/BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbolts/CancellationToken;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lbolts/CancellationTokenRegistration;
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:615)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:313)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:291)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:247)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:94)
    Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:607)
        ... 4 more

:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED
:transformClassesWithDexForRelease (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 22.043 secs.
```

I think this might be being caused by the change to a newer version of the Facebook SDK, but couldn't confirm it. Could you please help me out with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this relates to the second answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207350/didnt-find-class-bolts-applinks). This was caused because of [this fix](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2641). As a temporary workaround you can probably set the SDK to the older/deprecated facebook SDK with the build hint: `android.facebookSdkVersion=4.7.0`.

To property fix this problem (if that answer is indeed correct) you will need to add parse bolts to the build hints:

```
android.gradleDep=compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'; compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0';
```